# Retrieve unique elements with the highest date per element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list of objects about events that happened in different centres with different dates. I need to get a new list that show, for each centre, the date of the last event.

The list has a structure like this:

```
var eventsList = [
    {id: 1111, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/01/2019", [...Other info]},
    {id: 2222, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/02/2019", [...Other info]},
    {id: 3333, centre: "Beta", date: "01/01/2019", [...Other info]},
    {id: 4444, centre: "Beta", date: "02/01/2019", [...Other info]},
    {id: 5555, centre: "Omega", date: "01/03/2019", [...Other info]}]
```

The result list I want would have only one of each centre, with the highest date and no other info, like this:

```
var eventsList = [
    {centre: "Alpha", date: "01/02/2019"},
    {centre: "Beta", date: "02/01/2019"},
    {centre: "Omega", date: "01/03/2019"}]
```

I come up with a way of doing it by storing the entries in an object first (to prevent duplicates without searching a list) and then creating the final list from the object:

```
var objectList = {};
eventsList.forEach(function (element){
    var elementCentre = element.centre;
    var elementDate = element.date
    if (!objectList.hasOwnProperty(elementCentre) || objectList[elementCentre].date < elementDate) {
        objectList[elementCentre] = {centre: elementCentre, date: elementDate}
    }
});

return Object.values(objectList);
```

It works, but I don't really like it that much. I'm not sure if it's the best or most efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reduce and Date.parse to parse dates and than compare them

```js
var eventsList = [{id: 1111, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/01/2019"},{id: 2222, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/02/2019"},{id: 3333, centre: "Beta", date: "01/01/2019"},{id: 4444, centre: "Beta", date: "02/01/2019"},{id: 5555, centre: "Omega", date: "01/03/2019"}]
    

let op = eventsList.reduce((op,{centre,date})=>{
  if(op[centre]) {
    if(Date.parse(date) > Date.parse(op[centre].date)){
      op[centre] = {centre,date}
    }
  } else {
    op[centre] = {centre,date}
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. A lot cleaner than mine, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Use `.sort` and subtract your dates

You can subtract `Date` objects inside of a `.sort` call to simply run the built-in sorting method.

```js
const eventsList = [
    {centre: "Alpha", date: "01/02/2019"},
    {centre: "Beta", date: "02/01/2019"},
    {centre: "Omega", date: "01/03/2019"}]

eventsList.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))

console.log(eventsList)
```

**Note:** this sorts `eventsList` in place. To avoid sorting in place, try the following to create a copy then sort:

```js
[...eventsList].sort(/* ... */)
// or
eventsList.slice().sort(/* ... */)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in following steps.

- create an array of unique `centre` using `Set()` and `map()`
- Use `map()` on each value of the `cents`
- Inside `map()` use `filter()` on `eventLists` and use `sort()` on it and return first element

```js
var eventsList = [
    {id: 1111, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/01/2019"},
    {id: 2222, centre: "Alpha", date: "01/02/2019"},
    {id: 3333, centre: "Beta", date: "01/01/2019"},
    {id: 4444, centre: "Beta", date: "02/01/2019"},
    {id: 5555, centre: "Omega", date: "01/03/2019"}]
    
let cents = [...new Set(eventsList.map(x => x.centre))];
cents = cents.map(x => eventsList.filter(a => a.centre === x).sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))[0]);
console.log(cents)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the list by date, then remove all but the first event of each type. You can do this with a single sort and a single filter (with a findIndex inside it):

```
eventsList.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date));
eventsList = eventsList.filter((event, index) => {
    return index === eventsList.findIndex(ev => event.centre === ev.centre);
});
```